# How to make wocommerce shop products same heigt

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css, javascript, html

I'm trying to display the products with the **same height** at the shop page. I want **the product image aligned at the top** and **the add to cart buttons aligned at the bottom.**

**What I have right naw:**

[image]

**What I've tried so far:**

- Using javascript to set the `<li>` hight equal to it's parent `<ul>` hight. The result is the following:
  [image]

The js code is the following:

```
 //Script to align the products in shop page
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max = 0; 
        max = $("ul.products").height();
        $("ul.products li.product").height(max);


    });
```

This works as desired, the only problem is that I can't get the prices and buttons closer to the text.

- Applying a fixed height to the `li` elements.
  This breaks the responsive.

It must be an easy solution for that! Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for an update-proof solution, so overriding the default WooCommerce templates is not an option.

**EDIT 2**: I add the source code of the columns as asked in the comments.

```
   <div class="storefront-sorting">
<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
<ul class="products columns-3">
    <li class="product type-product post-223 status-publish first instock product_cat-accessories has-post-thumbnail featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
        <a href="http://localhost/testsite/product/whitening-fills/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
            <img width="324" height="324" src="https://placeholder.com/ 300" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://placeholder.com/ 300 324w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-416x416.jpg 416w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, iste error exercitationem quis, consectetur aspernatur architecto rem libero sunt repellat, dolorem, enim molestiae itaque. Officiis fuga ex illum distinctio reiciendis!</p>
        </a>
        <p class="font-weight-bold">39 €</p>
        <a href="?add-to-cart=223" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="223" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Elite Home Whitening Kit” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
    </li>
    <li class="product type-product post-64 status-publish instock product_cat-uncategorized has-post-thumbnail featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
        <a href="http://localhost/testsite/product/test-product/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
            <img width="324" height="324" src="https://placeholder.com/ 300" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://placeholder.com/ 300 324w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-416x416.jpg 416w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </a>
        <p class="font-weight-bold">40 €</p>
        <a href="?add-to-cart=64" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="64" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Smartphone Kit” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
    </li>
    <li class="product type-product post-279 status-publish last instock product_cat-uncategorized has-post-thumbnail featured shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
        <a href="http://localhost/testsite/product/whitening-trays/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
            <img width="324" height="324" src="https://placeholder.com/ 300" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://placeholder.com/ 300 324w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-416x416.jpg 416w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1-768x768.jpg 768w, http://localhost/testsite/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/thumbnail_Mockup1.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px">
            <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product 3</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga error asperiores aperiam ratione quasi cum laborum tenetur consequatur. Maxime quas at sint consequatur minima alias numquam earum facere repellendus modi.</p>
        </a>
        <p class="font-weight-bold">40 €</p>
        <a href="?add-to-cart=279" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="279" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Whitening trays” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="storefront-sorting"></div>
```

Comment: use absolute CSS property for buttons. Please share HTML code, so we can help more accurately

Comment: Hi Raashid, thank you for your answer. Setting absolute to the buttons wont work as the heigt of the columns is different. Which part of the code are you interested in? I was about to include some of the code but not sure which is relevant as woocommerce template is just always the same. Thanks!

Comment: please share the HTML of the columns.

Comment: Hi @RaashidDin, I've just updated the question with the source code of the columns. Hope this help! :)

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/spacing-the-flex-groups-with-equal-height-and-button-at-the-bottom/319421/2 This question matches your question. plz follow the same question. Flexbox is simple answer to the problem. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Raashid Din, this does not answer my question because as far as I know for using Flexbox I need to override the shop template and I'm just trying to avoid that. Is there any way to change the shop columns layout with hooks instead of template overriding?

Comment: Do one thing create a dummy local site at pantheon.io and install the same things on the site. In the future, if you need help you can easily refer the developers to the site. But for now, it will be easy for me to help you if you do this thing. Here is the link https://pantheon.io/register